# How to plot DataFrame as stacked bar chart after grouping

Tags: python

I am using a dataframe `DF`

And below is how I select from my data frame :

```
CountryList= DF[(DF['Sector'] == 'Test')].groupby(DF['Country'])['NumberI'].sum()
```

Which return the following :

```
print(CountryList)
    Country
    USA                    20
    CHINA                  30
    JAPAN                  10
```

Fact is that I don't understand How to plot a single bar with in it : 3 Color (1 for USA 1 for CHINA and 1 for JAPAN)

[image]

Comment: And how 20 should appear compared to 10? Wider horizontally or taller vertically?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov taller vertically. (My draw is not at scale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start as follows. The key here is to specify `bottom` parameter for `plt.bar` function, and to keep track of the current bottom, which is the sum of all previous heights.

I leave to you the process of making this plot beautiful

Also check out a more [complex example at the bottom of the web-page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_bar_plot.htm), where you can plot multiple such bars on a single plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [['usa', 20], ['china', 30], ['japan', 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['country', 'some_value'])

plt.figure(figsize=(4,10))
current_bottom = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.bar([0], row['some_value'], width=1, bottom=current_bottom, label=row['country'])
    plt.xlim(-2,2)
    current_bottom += row['some_value']
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick way to do it you can use the `plot` method of the DataFrame:

```
CountryList.T.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)
```